# Can i shuffle a string in python?

Tags: python, string, shuffle, password-generator

I created a password generator program and I have gotten the random letters, numbers, and symbols in quantities decided by the input. I can't seem to figure out how to shuffle the password, though.

> 

```
 import random 
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))


letterlist = []
numberlist = []
symbollist = []
for l in range(nr_letters):
  letterlist.append(random.choice(letters))
for n in range(nr_numbers):
  numberlist.append(random.choice(numbers))
for s in range(nr_symbols):
  symbollist.append(random.choice(symbols))
passwordlist = "".join(letterlist + numberlist + symbollist)
password = "".join(passwordlist)
print("Your password is "+password)
```

i can generate a random password eg adu145'!@ but i would like to scramble all the characters as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line before printing the password

```
password=''.join(random.sample(password,len(password)))
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) is the link for documentation of random.sample

Comment: Thank you so much it worked like a charm and I am  reading the documentation now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for

```
import random
help(random.shuffle)

Help on method shuffle in module random:

shuffle(x, random=None) method of random.Random instance
    Shuffle list x in place, and return None.

    Optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a
    random float in [0.0, 1.0); if it is the default None, the
    standard random.random will be used.
```